# Sequence asynchronous redux-observable actions

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'd like to sequence multiple async actions and when they are all finished, emit final actions:

```
const initializeEpic = (action$, state$, dependencies) =>
    action$.ofType("INITIALIZE_APP_REQUEST").pipe(
        mergeMap((action) => 
            [
                getUserRequest(),
                getCoreDataRequest(),
                // many other requests ...

                // now here I want to subscribe to GET_USER_SUCCESS,
                // GET_CORE_DATA_SUCCESS and other request "success" type's and 
                // once all are called, call initializeApp.success()
                // keep in mind that "..._SUCCESS" actions are called from
                // corresponding getUserEpic, getCoreDataEpic, etc...
            ]
        )
    )
```

I'm not sure if I'm trying to implement epic composition with good approach, but my idea in short is:

1. Call parent epic with `PARENT_REQUEST` action
2. Call child epics via corresponding `*_CHILD_REQUEST` action (child epics would catch it via `action$.ofType(*_CHILD_REQUEST)`)
3. Subscribe to `*_CHILD_SUCCESS` action within parent epic (which is dispatched from child epic)
4. Once all `*_CHILD_SUCCESS` actions are called, call `PARENT_SUCCESS`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `forkJoin`. You can do something like this:

```
const loadEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.ofType("INITIALIZE_APP_REQUEST").pipe(
    mergeMap((action) =>
      forkJoin([
        getUserRequest(),
        getCoreDataRequest()
      ]).pipe(
        map(([users, coreData]) =>
          initializeApp.success(users, coreData)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Please note that the requests are done simultaneously and not sequentially. You don't have to make it in sequence as long as they don't depend on each other.

Also, `getUserRequest()` and `getCoreDataRequest()` must return an observable, for eg:

```
function getUserRequest() {
  return from(axios.get(`/endpoint`)).pipe(map(response => response.data));
}
```